# sendmail generate new sendmail.cf

Tags: sendmail

I have changed hostname on my `Ubuntu 8.04` server but sendmail is still sending emails showing old hostname in the email headers 'From' field.

I have tried running command to re-generate my `sendmail.cf` but it ended up with the errors:

```
root@server:/etc/mail# m4 sendmail.mc > file.mc
*** ERROR: FEATURE() should be before MAILER()
*** MAILER(`local') must appear after FEATURE(`always_add_domain')*** ERROR: FEATURE() should be before MAILER()
*** MAILER(`local') must appear after FEATURE(`allmasquerade')*** ERROR: FEATURE() should be before MAILER()
```

Could you please help me to make sendmail see the new hostname? I am very new to sendmail, I have the default config.

Thanks.

P.S. hostname was changed through the manual editing of the 'hosts' file.

```
root@server:/etc/mail# sendmail -d0.4 -bv root 
Version 8.14.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You regenerate `sendmail.cf` by running `sendmailconfig`. Also check that `/etc/mailname` and `/etc/hostname` have the correct name.